# how to pass Multiple params with React?

Tags: reactjs, api, parameters

i have this :

```
 getScoreboardInfo: (title,pageSize,page,sort,callback) => {
const filter=`title@=${title}`
        return Service.get("scoreboard​/getinfos? filter=${filter}&sort=${sort}&Page=${Page}&PageSize=${PageSize}", (status, data) => {
          callback(status, data);
        });
      },
```

How should I send this to API as a query?

Comment: By Using backticks for the url?

Comment: Now it looks like this in the network scoreboard%E2%80%8B/getinfos/filter/sort/page/pageSize(/:$%7Bfilter%7D)(/:$%7Bsort%7D)(/:$%7Bpage%7D)(/:$%7BpageSize%7D)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the next approach

```js
const api = {
  getScoreboardInfo(options) {
    const params = formatObjectToQueryString(options);
    return Service.get(`scoreboard​/${params ? `?${params}` : ''}`, (status, data) => {
      callback(status, data);
    });
  },
};

// Examples:
// const object = {
//   firstName: 'John',
//   lastName: 'Doe',
//   age: undefined,
//   licence: null,
//   skill: '',
//   companyIds: [1, 2],
// };
// -> 'firstName=John&lastName=Doe&companyIds=1&companyIds=2'
export const formatObjectToQueryString = (object) => {
  return Object.entries(object)
    .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
      if (value === undefined || value === null || value === '') {
        return acc;
      }
      if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        return [
          ...acc,
          ...value.map(
            (itemValue) =>
              `${key}=${encodeURIComponent(
                typeof itemValue === 'string' ? itemValue : JSON.stringify(itemValue),
              )}`,
          ),
        ];
      }
      return [...acc, `${key}=${value}`];
    }, [])
    .join('&');
};
```